# Window does not assess elements from Kafka Source

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I think my perception of Flink windows may be wrong, since they are not evaluated as I would expect from the documentation or the Flink book. The goal is to join a Kafka topic, which has rather static data, with a Kafka topic with constantly incoming data.

```
env.addSource(createKafkaConsumer())
        .join(env.addSource((createKafkaConsumer()))))
        .where(keySelector())
        .equalTo(keySelector())
        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(2)))
        .apply(new RichJoinFunction<A, B>() { ... }
```

`createKafkaConsumer()` returns a FlinkKafkaConsumer

`keySelector()` is a placeholder for my key selector.

KafkaTopic A has 1 record, KafkaTopic B has 5. My understanding would be, that the JoinFunction is triggered 5 times (join condition is valid each time), resulting in 5 records in the sink. If a new record for topic A comes in within the 2 hours, another 5 records would be created (2x5 records). However, what comes through in the sink is rather unpredictable, I could not see a pattern. Sometimes there's nothing, sometimes the initial records, but if I send additional messages, they are not being processed by the join with prior records.

**My key question:**

What does even happen here? Are the records emitted *after* the window is done processing? I would expect a real-time output to the sink, but that would explain a lot.

Related to that:
Could I handle this problem with onElement trigger or would this make my TimeWindow obsolete? Do those two concepts exists parallel to each other, i.e. that the join window is 2 hours, but the join function + output is triggered per element? How about duplicates in that case?

Subsequently, does processing time mean the point in time, when the record is consumed from the topic? So if I e.g. `setStartFromEarliest()` on start, all messages which were consumed within the next two hours, were in that window?

Additional info:
`env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);` is set and I also switched to EventTime in between.

Comment: I really don't get it, I started a new job, set the Window to 2 minutes, set both Consumers to read from beginning (each topic had 10 records) and everything comes out of the join as it should, **before** the job was even running 2 minutes.. 2 hours on the contrary did not, however it showed the window having 20 records received. I cannot make sense out of that, the Logs do not show any error and the jobs do not fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of a tumbling processing time window is that it processes all events which fall into the given timespan. In your case, it is 2 hours. Per default, the window will only output results once the 2 hours are over because it needs to know that no other events will be coming for this window.

If you want to output early results (e.g. for every incoming record), then you could specify a custom `Trigger` which fires on every element. See [the Trigger API docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#triggers) for more information about this.

#### Update

The window time does not start with the first element but the window starts at multiples of the window length. For example, if your window size is 2 hours, then you can only have windows `[0, 2)`, `[2, 4)`, ... but not `[1, 3)`, `[3, 5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, so it behaves as I assumed. However, in this case I got strange behaviour in the sense that sometimes (e.g. on initial startup), records are emitted before the time window is finished. For example when starting the job with a window of 10 minutes, a bunch of records reaches the output immediately, way before the job even passes the 2 minute mark. Do you also have an explanation for that?

Comment: I'm not quite getting what you're hinting towards. When you write `[0,2)`, is that the time passed from the timestamp I started the job on (amount of time unit) or full hours (or the time unit respectively) on the clock, regardless of when I started the job? Lets say I started the job with 10 minute window at 13:37:49, is the time window evaluated until 13:47:49 or until 13:40:00 and the next time window will be from there to 13:50?

Comment: If you start the program at 13:47, then the first window will start at 13:40 and end 13:50. Hence you see after 3 minutes the output of the first window.